# SASS Calc Interpolation

Tags: css, sass, bourbon

I have a SASS variable:

```
$default-padding: 15px
```

I want to use this to set a CSS width property using the calc function.

I have various calculations to make based on the value of the $default-padding variable. For Example, the width would be 100% - (2 * $default-padding). As there is padding on the left and on the right.

I am trying to set a local variable (using Bourbon's strip-unit method):

```
$default-padding-left-and-right: #{(strip-unit($default-padding) * 2)}px;
```

I would expect the result of this variable to be 30px in this use case, and I want to use it in the following rule:

```
.popup {
    width: calc(100% - #{$default-padding-left-and-right});
}
```

This doesn't work, the resultant CSS is:

```
.popup {
    width: calc(100% - strip-unit(15px)px);
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Will `$default-padding` always be a `px` value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things:

1. it seems like the strip-unit function is not found (why the function
   name is printed out)
2. you should not interpolate the $default-padding-left-and-right (it turns the variable value into a string) – use multiply instead.

Example :

```
@function strip-unit($num) { @return $num / ($num * 0 + 1); }

$default-padding: 15px;
$default-padding-left-and-right: strip-unit($default-padding) * 2px;

.popup {
  width: calc(100% - #{$default-padding-left-and-right});
}
```

Output:

```
.popup {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, not sure why strip-unit isn't found. It's only not found if I do a multiplication on the result.

Answer (score 0):

The Bourbon function is `strip-units` not `strip-unit` - changing this should resolve your issue

Comment: I'm using Bourbon 4.3: 

WARNING: [Bourbon] [Deprecation] `strip-units` is deprecated and will be removed in 5.0.0. Use the renamed `strip-unit` function instead.